# I'm using jQuery boxy plugin for Ajax modal pop up window

Tags: php, jquery

I'm using jQuery boxy plug in for Ajax modal pop up window and and populating it through Ajax. In that window populate combo box using Ajax first time it will populate. But when I close modal window and again open it and hit the button, the combo box does not populate.

I'm using php as server side language.

How to fix it and where am I making a mistake?

Here is the code

Comment: Please edit your answer to include code

Comment: Is your combo box being populated with an Ajax request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had an issue like this.

Remember that any javascript that is returned in your Ajax response will not be executed. All javascript needs to be loaded and bound to the correct elements when the first page loads.